# Generating list of integers with given number of bit set and sum of bit indices

Tags: recursion, bit-manipulation

I would like to generate in an efficient way a list of integers (preferably ordered)
with the following defining properties:

1. All integers have the same number of bit set `N`.
2. All integers have the same sum of bit indices `K`.

To be definite, for an integer `I`
its binary representation is:

```
$I=\sum_{j=0}^M c_j 2^j$ where $c_j=0$ or $1$
```

The number of bit sets is:

```
$N(I)=\sum_{j=0}^M c_j$
```

The sum of bit indices is:

```
$K(I)=\sum_{j=0}^M j c_j$
```

I have an inefficient way to generate the list as follows:
make a  do/for loop over integers incrementing by use
of a "snoob" function - smallest next integer with same number of bit set
and at each increment checking if it has the correct value of K

this is grossly inefficient because in general starting from an integer
with the correct `N` and `K` value the snoob integer from `I` does not have the correct `K` and one has to make many snoob calculations to get the next integer
with both `N` and `K` equal to the chosen values.
Using snoob gives an ordered list which is handy for dichotomic search but
not absolutely compulsory.

Counting the number of elements in this list is easily done by recursion
when viewed as a partition numner counting. here is a recursive function in fortran 90 doing that job:

```
=======================================================================
recursive function BoundedPartitionNumberQ(N, M, D)  result (res)
implicit none

  ! number of partitions of N into M distinct integers, bounded by D
  ! appropriate for Fermi counting rules

   integer(8) :: N, M, D, Nmin
   integer(8) :: res
    
    Nmin = M*(M+1)/2       ! the Fermi sea
    
    if(N < Nmin) then
        res = 0

    else if((N == Nmin) .and. (D >= M)) then
        res = 1

    else if(D < M) then
       res = 0

    else if(D == M)  then
       if(N == Nmin) then
              res = 1
       else 
              res = 0  
       endif

    else if(M == 0) then
       res = 0

     else

     res = BoundedPartitionNumberQ(N-M,M-1,D-1)+BoundedPartitionNumberQ(N-M,M,D-1)

     endif

    end function BoundedPartitionNumberQ
========================================================================================
```

My present solution is inefficient when I want to generate lists with several `$10^7$`
elements. Ultimately I want to stay within the realm of C/C++/Fortran and reach lists of lengths
up to a few `$10^9$`

my present f90 code is the following:

```
program test
implicit none

integer(8) :: Nparticles
integer(8) :: Nmax, TmpL, CheckL, Nphi
integer(8) :: i, k, counter
integer(8) :: NextOne

Nphi = 31        ! word size is Nphi+1
Nparticles = 16  ! number of bit set

print*,Nparticles,Nphi

Nmax = ishft(1_8, Nphi + 1) - ishft(1_8, Nphi + 1 - Nparticles)

i = ishft(1, Nparticles) - 1

counter = 0

! integer CheckL is the sum of bit indices

CheckL = Nparticles*Nphi/2  ! the value of the sum giving the largest list

do while(i .le. Nmax)   ! we increment the integer

    TmpL = 0

    do k=0,Nphi
        if (btest(i,k)) TmpL = TmpL + k
    end do

    if (TmpL == CheckL) then    ! we check whether the sum of bit indices is OK

        counter = counter + 1

    end if

    i = NextOne(i)   ! a version of "snoob" described below

end do

print*,counter

end program

!==========================================================================
function NextOne (state)
implicit none

integer(8) :: bit    
integer(8) :: counter 
integer(8) :: NextOne,state,pstate

bit     =  1
counter = -1
  
!  find first one bit 

do  while (iand(bit,state) == 0)

    bit = ishft(bit,1)

end do

!  find next zero bit 

do  while (iand(bit,state) /= 0)
    
    counter = counter + 1
    bit = ishft(bit,1)

end do

if (bit == 0) then 

    print*,'overflow in NextOne'
    NextOne = not(0)
  
else 

    state = iand(state,not(bit-1))  ! clear lower bits i &= (~(bit-1));

    pstate = ishft(1_8,counter)-1 ! needed by IBM/Zahir compiler

 !  state = ior(state,ior(bit,ishft(1,counter)-1)) ! short version OK with gcc

    state = ior(state,ior(bit,pstate))

    NextOne = state

end if

end function NextOne
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic recursive implementation could be:

```
void listIntegersWithWeight(int currentBitCount, int currentWeight, uint32_t pattern, int index, int n, int k, std::vector<uint32_t> &res)
{
    if (currentBitCount > n ||
        currentWeight > k)
        return;

    if (index < 0)
    {
        if (currentBitCount == n && currentWeight == k)
            res.push_back(pattern);
    }
    else
    {
        listIntegersWithWeight(currentBitCount, currentWeight, pattern, index - 1, n, k, res);
        listIntegersWithWeight(currentBitCount + 1, currentWeight + index, pattern | (1u << index), index - 1, n, k, res);
    }
}
```

That is not my suggestion, just the starting point. On my PC, for `n = 16, k = 248`, both this version and the iterative version take almost (but not quite) 9 seconds. Almost exactly the same amount of time, but that's just a coincidence. More pruning can be done:

- `currentBitCount + index + 1 < n` if the number of set bits cannot reach `n` with the number of unfilled positions that are left, continuing is pointless.
- `currentWeight + (index * (index + 1) / 2) < k` if the sum of positions cannot reach `k`, continuing is pointless.

Together:

```
void listIntegersWithWeight(int currentBitCount, int currentWeight, uint32_t pattern, int index, int n, int k, std::vector<uint32_t> &res)
{
    if (currentBitCount > n || 
        currentWeight > k ||
        currentBitCount + index + 1 < n ||
        currentWeight + (index * (index + 1) / 2) < k)
        return;

    if (index < 0)
    {
        if (currentBitCount == n && currentWeight == k)
            res.push_back(pattern);
    }
    else
    {
        listIntegersWithWeight(currentBitCount, currentWeight, pattern, index - 1, n, k, res);
        listIntegersWithWeight(currentBitCount + 1, currentWeight + index, pattern | (1u << index), index - 1, n, k, res);
    }
}
```

On my PC with the same parameters, this only takes half a second. It can probably be improved further.

Comment: how would you invoke such a function from the main ? sorry but the initial values are obscure to me. And also I guess that it works fine with uint64_t or even uint128_t (compiler permitting)?

Comment: @Blaise for example `listIntegersWithWeight(0, 0, 0, 31, n, k, res)` for 32bit integers, 31 being the index of the highest bit. With minor changes it would work for larger types, `1u << index` would need to change to take the wider type into account

Comment: the recursive solution is very efficient. Generating a list of length 1.5 billion in the case n=15 highest index=42 and k=15*21 (worst case scenario) takes only 32s with g++ -O3 on a recent PC. Solves the bottleneck I had (there are others of course)

Comment: @Blaise btw as a useful variant, if you switch the order of the two recursive calls, then the list is generated in reverse-sorted order.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned C/C++/Fortran, I've tried to keep this relatively [language agnostic/easily transferable](https://ideone.com/263IfL) but have also included [*faster* builtins alternatives](https://ideone.com/dILgpB) where applicable.

> All integers have the same number of bit set `N`

Then we can also say, **all valid integers will be permutations of N set bits.**

First, we must generate the initial/min permutation:

```
uint32_t firstPermutation(uint32_t n){
    // Fill the first n bits (on the right)
    return (1 << n) -1;
}
```

Next, we must set the final/max permutation  - indicating the 'stop point':

```
uint32_t lastPermutation(uint32_t n){
    // Fill the last n bits (on the left)
    return (0xFFFFFFFF >> n) ^ 0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

Finally, we need a way to get the next permutation.

```
uint32_t nextPermutation(uint32_t n){
    uint32_t t = (n | (n - 1)) + 1;
    return t | ((((t & -t) / (n & -n)) >> 1) - 1);
}

// or with builtins:
uint32_t nextPermutation(uint32_t &p){
    uint32_t t = (p | (p - 1));
    return (t + 1) | (((~t & -~t) - 1) >> (__builtin_ctz(p) + 1));
}
```

---

> All integers have the same sum of bit indices `K`

**Assuming these are *integers* (32bit), you can use this DeBruijn sequence** to quickly identify the index of the first set bit - *fsb*.
Similar sequences exist for other types/bitcounts, for example [this](https://www.chessprogramming.org/De_Bruijn_Sequence_Generator) one could be adapted for use.

By stripping the current *fsb*, we can apply the aforementioned technique to identify index of the next *fsb*, and so on.

```
int sumIndices(uint32_t n){
    const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = {
      0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8,
      31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
    };

    int sum = 0;
    // Get fsb idx
    do sum += MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((uint32_t)((n & -n) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];        
    // strip fsb
    while (n &= n-1);   

    return sum;
}

// or with builtin
int sumIndices(uint32_t n){
    int sum = 0;
    do sum += __builtin_ctz(n);
    while (n &= n-1);
    return sum;
}
```

---

Finally, we can iterate over each permutation, checking if the sum of all indices matches the specified K value.

```
p = firstPermutation(n);
lp = lastPermutation(n);

do {
    p = nextPermutation(p);
    if (sumIndices(p) == k){
        std::cout << "p:" << p << std::endl;
    }
} while(p != lp);
```

You could easily change the 'handler' code to do something similar starting at a given integer - using it's N & K values.

---

[image: benchmark of intrinsic vs self-implemented]

Comment: Thanks for your very nice implementation. However it is only marginally faster than my own solution which I added in the original post. If I look at the case with the biggest list with fixed number of bit sets 32-bit word, 16 set bits and sum of bit indices equal to 8*31 then the list has dimension 8908546 and is generated by your C++ code in 28s with g++ -O0 and 12s with g++ -O3

Comment: while my f90 implementation generated the same list in 70s with gfortran -O0 and 15s with gfortran -O3. It is not immediately clear to me how to use this deBruijn technique with 64-bit integers.

Comment: @Blaise Have clarified the section on debrujin sequences - they exist for other bit counts as well. I've linked one you could likely adapt.

Comment: @harold Agreed, I've updated to included builtin alternatives where applicable.